# Inserting Search Bar into Web Page

Tags: html, search, web

I am looking at inserting a Search Bar into my intranet Page however there is no were to show a source code for a simple search bar. All i am looking to do is search through all the Intranet Pages and find related documents. E.G. QM11.

If the result could turn up on a separate page that would be great. Even if someone had a link to a tutorial page.

Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this website helps you out to some extent:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609/Adding-a-search-facility-to-your-website

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't think it was this involved. Unforunitly i am working on a work computer and the web page is on a different server. So i cannot change the settings on my computer. Is it easier to make a java script and than install the Java into the page?

Comment: Aditi this is a "link only answer" I would recommend improving your answer or moving it to a comment. Link Only answers are not useful for future visitors as the links may die one day :)